# Redirect non authenticated user to login page (for all views)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-middleware

I am looking to redirect my user to `login` page, if they have not logged in.

I initally looked at the decorator `@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')`.

But this is not ideal, for 2 reasons: first I want this to apply to all views. Also the decorator returns an error message when I try to login with allauth.

I am sure this is solvable, but I am looking for a solution that could apply to all views.

I found something using `authmiddleware`(doc: https://pypi.org/project/django-authmiddleware/). However the code doesn't not seem to be responsive, in the sense nothing is happening and the logs on the console don't seem to pick up anything.

Can someone see what I am doing wrong?

**base.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    'AuthMiddleware.middleware.AuthRequiredMiddleware', 
]
AUTH_SETTINGS = {

    "LOGIN_URL" : "login_user",
    "DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL" : None,
    "REDIRECT_AFTER_LOGIN" : False,

}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse

def list_event(request): #ADDED FOLLOWING REQUEST IN COMMENTS
    event_list = Event.objects.all
    return render(request, 'main/list_event.html',{'event_list':event_list})

class AuthRequiredMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login_user'))
        return None
```

Comment: Use a mix of authentication backend and Login URL settings and leave the rest to Django. Please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users

Comment: Can you post one or all of the views that you DONT want to be public please?

Comment: Hi all, to answer @misraX, I am not sure how the link helps me answering my problem as I am looking to use a solution that would apply to all views. In the link embedded, it seems the solution suggests that I enter either a decorator or some line of code in each view. I am looking for something more scalable. Unless I am reading this wrong?

Comment: @Swift it's literally, all the views I dont want the public to see (with the exception of login/signup). I will add a random view from the code since you ask, let me know if you have some ideas :)

Comment: It was more that I was wondering if you're using function based views or class based views was all. Just an example would suffice. Middleware will effect EVERY request, which might not be the desired behaviour

Comment: Ah! Its mostly function based views. (there is a few CBV too). I edited the initial post and added one of the views.

Comment: Is there an error you get when trying to implement your middleware?

Comment: @Swift no, thats the most frustrating thing. I did get a few on my first tries : (1)I did not install the middleware's pack, (2) I wasnt pointing to the right path. But by following the documentation advising to enter `AuthMiddleware.middleware.AuthRequiredMiddleware` solved this. Since then not errors.

Comment: Does it still not produce the desired behaviour despite not errors?

Comment: Not. It's like the code is being ignored. There is no error, but also no reaction. The logs in the console are also quite about it. There must be a connection between the settings and the views that is not happening.

Comment: Does it print anything if you add a debug `print()` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an alternative solution and thought I would leave it there.

I used a tutorial on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axsaC62UQOc) which, with a few changes (the video is old), works like a charm. Its about 3 videos 30 minutes very well explained.

Here it goes:

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

    '[yourappname].middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware', 
]

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS =( #<-- I am using allauth, so left some examples here)
    r'logout',
    r'register_user',
    r'accounts/google/login/',
    r'accounts/social/signup/',
    r'accounts/facebook/login/',
    
)
```

**middleware.py** (this files goes in your main app, by default "mysite")

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    pass
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        
    def __call__ (self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
    
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request,'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        print(path)
        
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            if not any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS):
                return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

Comment: I was about to suggest a very similar solution, but you found it by yourself. But make sure it works as you expect it! `process_view()` method is deprecated in middlewares since Django 1.10 ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware)).

Comment: In addition, as an alternative to standard `redirect()`, you should use [`redirect_to_login()` helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#helper-functions) to simplify the redirection to login page. It allows to pass a "next" page so user is automatically redirected to the first page he wanted to open after a successful login.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was actually working redirection a few days ago. Made it work eventually expect for AllAuth. Was considering creating an overriding view to allow the redirection to previous page.  Do you think the helper could avoid me having to create the overriding view? (will try tonight)

Comment: Just tested the code, it produces the same result as what I currently have (for redirection), however it does not seem to work when the user goes from Login to Register page, and register an account. In this occasion the user is sent back to '`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`. Am I missing a quick fix?

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
return redirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.login_user, request.path))'
```

instead of `HttpResponse`?

Comment: Hi there, this did not solve the problem unfortunately. I think my problem is located in the lines above. (or in the base.py) Not sure, I thought I mis-installed the middleware, or dont call it properly.